# Synaptic Package Manger is not launching in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

This is Sushanta, started familiarizing with Ubuntu Linux. After a successful installation of Ubuntu version 18.04 in my Fujitsu Life book U772 tried to launch Synaptic Package Manager. Unfortunately, It's not opening. I ask for your kind suggestion in this regard as I need to get access to some software like Dropbox and so on.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're probably referring to the software center. please open terminal and type `ubuntu-software` then if it doesn't open, you should see some output with errors in the terminal. Please paste them in your question

Comment: It can't find.   And shows something like :                                sushanta@sushanta-LIFEBOOK-U772:~$ ubuntu_software

Command 'ubuntu_software' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ubuntu-software' from deb ubuntu-software

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>                                                 @janmyszkier

Comment: Please **edit your question** rather than add various new information in comments here and there. copy and paste output from the terminal in your question and then format it as *code* by using the { } icon on the top of the edit question window.

Comment: Well, So far I know Ubuntu Desktop; 18.04 LTS is not a server, which I download and operating now. Would you be so kind suggesting me @user68186

Comment: Did you realize that you tried "ubuntu_software" instead of "ubuntu-software"?

Answer (score 1):

I spent almost one day to discover the mystery behind this trouble as I am new here. Anyway, I am answering my question that Synaptic Package Manager does not work on Wayland session where I log in on that session. That's why it was showing errors all the time. This could be helpful for newcomers like me. Anyone should check the log on options by clicking on settings icon appears at the beginning to avoid this kind of problems. Finally, Thanks, everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install synaptic
```

to install Synaptic Package Manger.

For Dropbox you can run in terminal

```
sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox
```

Comment: The user is asking about installing Dropbox which cannot be done through synaptic.

Comment: Dear Mr. @Graham  The SPM is already installed and updated. The problem is that it's not launching it after submitting my password.